# Module sharing and dynamic properties on Express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

I am new to NodeJS / Express and I have this issue related to global/module sharing of modules and configuration settings that I will try to explain here.

A simple example is trying to unit test a middleware module that includes other libraries. As follows:

**config/settings.js**

```
module.exports = {
...,
debugLevel: 3
```

};

**middleware/auth.js**

```
// Required modules for middleware
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var config = require('../config/settings');

var log = require('../libraries/logger')('middlewares/auth');
...

// Middleware methods
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var middleware = {};

middleware.apicall = function(req, res, next) {
    ...
    log.info('Made api call');
};
```

**libraries/logger.js**

```
// External Dependencies
var winston = require('winston');
var winlogger =  new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)()
    ]
});
winlogger.cli();


var logger = function(module, debug) {
    this.module = module;
    this.logger = winlogger;
    this.debugLevel = debugLevel;
};

logger.prototype = {
    module: '',
    logger: null,
    debugLevel: 3,


    /**
     * Generic Log function
     *
     * @param level
     * @param str
     * @param data
     */
    debug: function(level, str, data) {
        if ( this.debugLevel > 2) this.logger.log(level, this.module+' - '+str, data);
    },

    /**
     * Specific function for info
     *
     * @param str
     * @param data
     */
    info: function(str, data) {
        if ( this.debugLevel > 1 ) this.logger.info(this.module+' - '+str, data);
    }
};
```

**tests/api.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const should  = chai.should;
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;

// Node Http Mocks
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
var middleware = require('../middlewares/auth');

describe("Test API Call", function() {

    it("should give 200 over api call", function(done) {
        var req = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/test',
            params: {}
        });
        var res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        middleware.apicall(req, res, function(res) { return res; });

        assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);

        done();
    });

});
```

Now all this works but the problem i am having is: **how can I do the tests without the log line from apicall method showing up ?**

Is there a way for the settings to be globally present ? Or a way to structure the app so that you can inject the settings coming from one single require in app.js ?

I would need to do, in tests/api.js,  something like this:

```
var config = require('../config/settings');
config.debug = 0;
```

and inject it into the test probably. Anyone faced a similar challenge ?

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

Having not found a solution, I tried to make a series of tests and came up with a solution that works.

We make use of globals for this particular case. So:

**bin\www**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var app = require('../app');
...
var http = require('http');

global.config = require('../config/settings');
global.log = require('../libraries/logger')('server');

...
```

**app.js**

```
// Node framework dependencies
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var config = global.config;
var path = require('path');
var log = global.log;
log.setLabel('app');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var validator = require('express-validator');
...
```

**tests\api.js**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const should  = chai.should;
const expect = chai.expect;
const assert = chai.assert;

global.config = require('../config/settings');
config.debug = false;
global.log = require('../libraries/logger')('Test case');

...
// Node Http Mocks
var httpMocks = require('node-mocks-http');
var middleware = require('../middlewares/auth');


describe("Test API Call", function() {
    it("should give 200 over api call", function(done) {
        var req = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/test',
            params: {}
        });
        var res = httpMocks.createResponse();
        middleware.apicall(req, res, function(res) { return res; });
        assert.equal(res.statusCode, 200);
        done();
    });
});
```